# OPA Rego rule to check annotation in k8s namespace with other rules

Tags: kubernetes, open-policy-agent, rego

I want to check if an annotation exist in a namespace, if not deny. I have this code but not working. How can I get the right object path ( namespace.annotation ) to compare to  ?

```
  violation[{"msg": msg, "details": {}}] {
        input.request.kind.kind == "Namespace"
        not input.review.object.metadata.annotations.hostPath
        msg := sprintf("no hostpath defined in namespace for this pod %v, [input.review.object.metadata.name])
    }
```

I have both pod and namespace specified in my constrains since I need rules that check both in my template

```
spec:
  match:
    kinds:
      - apiGroups: [""]
        kinds: ["Pod"]
      - apiGroups: [""]
        kinds: ["Namespace"]
```

thanks !

Comment: are you sure that `input.review` is a valid path? I think that you only have `input.request` and (depends on configuration) `input.response`

Answer (score 1):

Check it out [this nearly identical example](https://github.com/open-policy-agent/gatekeeper-library/blob/master/library/general/requiredlabels/src.rego#L13) from the gatekeeper library repository.
I think the specific issue is with the way you are extracting the annotation itself (notice the example is using square brackets while you are using a dot notation).